# ClassNotFoundException scala.runtime.LambdaDeserialize when spark-submit spark version 3.0.2, scala version 2.12.10

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, spark-submit

I followed Spark SimpleApp tutorial as mentioned here https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications

My build.sbt looks like

```
name := "HelloScala"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.0.2"
```

Also On here http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/ it mentions that
`Spark runs on Java 8/11, Scala 2.12, ...`

However, when I do spark-submit

```
spark-submit
--class "SimpleApp" \
--master local[4] \
target/scala-2.12/helloscala_2.12-0.1.jar
```

I get following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.runtime.LambdaDeserialize
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 63 more
```

Any idea what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I build Spark from master branch (v3.1.2), whereas the application I am running is using spark 3.0.2 dependencies.